# How can I store temporary, self-destroying data into a t-sql table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temporary

Suppose I have a table which contains relevant information. However, the data is only relevant for, let's say, 30 minutes.

After that it's just database junk, so I need to get rid of it asap.

If I wanted, I could clean this table periodically, setting an expiration date time for each record individually and deleting expired records through a job or something. This is my #1 option, and it's what will be done unless someone convince me otherwise.

But I think this solution may be problematic. What if someone stops the job from running and no one notices? I'm looking for something like a built-in way to insert temporary data into a table. Or a table that has "volatile" data itself, in a way that it automagically removes data after x amount of time after its insertion.

And last but not least, if there's no built-in way to do that, could I be able to implement this functionality in SQL server 2008 (or 2012, we will be migrating soon) myself? If so, could someone give me directions as to what to look for to implement something like it?

(Sorry if the formatting ends up bad, first time using a smartphone to post on SO)

Comment: Are u sure you want to do this on SQL side? This sounds like a cache, and you're better of using other cache solutions (e.g. ASP.NET has a caching mechanism etc.)

Comment: You can create table, and set Sql-Server agent job to truncate it periodically on set intervals.

Comment: If I truncate it periodically, I'll accidentally kill a lot of records that  didn't expire yet. Also I want to do this on SQL side because a lot of different machines may query/insert data into this table. I feel like building up a distributed cache just for a single functionality is overkill and will bring me more problems than solve them. To explain it better, this table will be a short log of events that may change the behavior of the other machines upon reading it, temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer indicated, TRUNCATE TABLE is a fast way to remove the contents of a table, but it's aggressive; it will completely empty the table. Also, there are restrictions on its use; among others, it can't be used on tables which "[are referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx)".

Any more targeted removal of rows will require a DELETE statement with a WHERE clause. Having an index on relevant criteria fields (such as the insertion date) will improve performance of the deletion and might be a good idea (depending on its effect on INSERT and UPDATE statements).

You will need something to "trigger" the DELETE statement (or TRUNCATE statement). As you've suggested, a SQL Server Agent job is an obvious choice, but you are worried about the job being disabled or removed. Any solution will be vulnerable to someone removing your work, but there are more obscure ways to trigger an activity than a job. You could embed the deletion into the insertion process-- either in whatever stored procedure or application code you have, or as an actual table trigger. Both of those methods increase the time required for an INSERT and, because they are not handled out of band by the SQL Server Agent, will require your users to wait slightly longer. If you have the right indexes and the table is reasonably-sized, that might be an acceptable trade-off.

There isn't any other capability that I'm aware of for SQL Server to just start deleting data. There isn't automatic data retention policy enforcement.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just out of curiosity, I suppose SQL server isn't extensible to this point then? I mean, without using a trigger, I assume I couldn't create another "kind" of table which could be able to handle this job upon insertion of data. Right?

Comment: There are a number of creative ways to accomplish the purging, but it still has to be triggered. Data at rest tends to stay at rest. :) You could write a separate app which had its own timer-- even something at the OS level like a scheduled task. You might be able to somehow use Service Broker but ultimately something needs to call the service. You could maybe do something weird like having a DDL trigger based on a maintenance plan or some other predictable event, but that's still basically keyed off of the SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 0):

See @Yuriy comment, that's relevant.

If you really need to implement it DB side....

Truncate table is fast way to get rid of records.
If all you need is **ONE** table and you just need to fill it with data, use it and dispose it asap you can consider truncating a (permanent) "CACHE_TEMP" table.

The scenario can become more complicated you are running concurrent threads/jobs and each is handling it's own data.

If that data is just existing for a single "job"/context you can consider using #TEMP tables. They are a bit volatile and maybe can be what you are looking for.

Also you maybe can use table variables, they are a bit more volatile than temporary tables but it depends on things you don't posted, so I cannot say what's really better.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` would delete all records, including those which have not aged out yet.